# Radio button policy

Tags: forms, radio-button

Do radio buttons have policy of setting default value? I want to create form where are radio buttons and it is required value. What is better to select one on show form or show all and put error message(if any radio button, not selected on submit)?

Comment: I'm not sure is there any general policy. You need to adapt it depends on requirements. Honestly, I always choose combo box(with default empty message) over radio button...

Answer (score 0):

You can select a default radio value by using checked

```
<input type=radio name=r1 value="1" checked>
<input type=radio name=r1 value="2">
```

Here default value is set to 1, v should use checked keyword.

It is better to set default radio button option. 
Suppose if u dont want to use default radio button selection You can call a js function(using onsubmit()). Like this

```
<form id="ID" method="post" action="servleName" onSubmit="return validateOption()">
<input type=radio name=r1 value="1" >A</input>

<input type=radio name=r1 value="2">B</input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><span id="error" style="display:none;"></span>
</form>
```

Your script goes here to validate whether option selected or not,Submission of page is possible only if onsubmit=true ie if validateOption() returns true.

```
<script>
function validateOption()
{
    var group=document.getElementsByName("r1");

     for ( var i = 0; i < group.length; i++)
     { 
         if (group[i].checked) 
             return true;
             }
        // else you can show error message like this
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Please enter your choice";
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Of course, you can add default value and add validation message. But question was: Should I selected radio button or not if I have required value of radio button on  form?

Comment: @sajili not necessary.